# Não consigo solucionar esse problema na minha automação de testes

Tags: ruby, testes, testes-automatizados, cucumber

Já tentei quase de tudo e ainda continuo tomando esse erro na minha automação de testes em ruby:  incompatible encoding regexp match (Windows-1252 regexp with UTF-8 string) (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Já verifiquei nomenclatura de pasta, removi caracteres especiais da feature mas sem sucesso, sou novo na área de automação quem pouder me ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: Pessoal consegui resolver esse problema segue soloução:

erros windows utf 8 acessar painel de controle > regiao > aba administrativo alterar localidade do sistema > marcar checkbox Beta: usar unicode UTF-8 para suporte de linguagem mundial

Comment: Parece ser um problema na escolha de caracteres da sua expressão regular. Eu não recomendaria trocar o encoding do sistema como você fez e sim só acertar o regex. Mas não tenho muita experiência com isso para falar.